# haproxy: share port between HTTPS and XMPP

Tags: xmpp, haproxy

Followed the myriads of tutorials and still no go.  I don't need haproxy to handle SSL as I'm passing https directly to the nginx SSL port and XMPP also has its own encryption.

Here is what I have (MY.DOMAIN is valid for the nginx SSL cert).  **Everything always falls through to XMPP**.  I'm also open to reversing the approach - does anyone have a reliable way to detect XMPP (with SSL)?

```
global
    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon
    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    120s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1440m  # Modified
    timeout server          1440m  # Modified
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000
frontend  main
    mode tcp
    bind :443 
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    #Neither of these work:
    #use_backend www-ssl        if  { req.ssl_hello_type 1 }  
    use_backend www-ssl        if  { req.ssl_sni -i MY.DOMAIN  }  
    default_backend xmpp
    option tcplog
    log global
backend xmpp
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    server app1 127.0.0.1:5222
backend www-ssl
    mode tcp
    server www-ssl 127.0.0.1:1443
```

Answer (score 0):

The above configuration actually ***is*** working.  I had some redirect on the backend that confused me.

I'm not 100% sure that it's working all the time (for example, curl is getting XMPP and I'm not sure what's so different about curl's SSL), but at least for Chrome requests the HTTPS detection is working.

UPDATE: adding this to frontend makes it work for curl and browsers:

```
acl content_present req_len gt 0
tcp-request content accept if content_present
```